# Android EditText view Floating Hint in Material Design

Tags: android, text, hint

Does API 21 provide a method to use the following feature:

http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-floating-labels

I'm trying to float the EditText hints.

Thanks!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/11247418

Comment: I ran into this as well during my search, but was wondering if Android provided a native method.

Comment: This make us think that something is wrong with Android. There are several missing gaps on the API for Material Design. Another example is Float Action Button.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to add the following to your module build.gradle file:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
```

And use com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout in your XML:

```
       <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/my_hint">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="UserName"/>
   </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 109):

Floating hint EditText:

Add below dependency in gradle:

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

In layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="UserName"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Beware of: [TextInputLayout not showing EditText hint before user focus on it](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30537413/1608670) bug exists in design support library `22.2.0`

Comment: What's the difference between using EditText and TextInputEditText in this XML ?

Comment: The newly renamed dependency seems to be `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-rc01'`.

Answer (score 60):

Yes, as of May 29, 2015 this functionality is now provided in the [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

This library includes support for

- Floating labels
- Floating action button
- Snackbar
- Navigation drawer
- and more

Comment: Do you happen to know of a tutorial for floating labels with EditTexts like OP mentioned?

Comment: Yes.  https://blog.stylingandroid.com/textinputlayout/ and http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-a-login-screen-using-textinputlayout--cms-24168 and http://hmkcode.com/android-textinputlayout/

Comment: Wow, thanks! I will look through these and let you know how it goes!

Comment: The third one was what I was looking for. I stumbled upon TextInputLayout, but couldn't find a good example (probably searching all the wrong terms). Thanks!

Answer (score 18):

The Android support library can be imported within gradle in the dependencies :

```
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

It should be included within GradlePlease! And as an example to use it:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/to_text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextViewTo"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="To"
        android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
        />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Btw, the editor may not understand that AutoCompleteTextView is allowed within TextInputLayout.

Answer (score 12):

Android hasn't provided a native method. Nor the AppCompat.

Try this library: https://github.com/rengwuxian/MaterialEditText

This might be what you want.

Comment: I get Error:(1) "Attribute "color" has already been defined" on gradle sync, probably because of the appcompat-v7. I can't get rid of it. Anny suggestions?

Comment: MaterialEditText hasn't defined an attribute named "color", so it must be something wrong elsewhere.

Answer (score 9):

Import the Support Libraries, In your project's build.gradle file, add the following lines in the project's dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
}
```

Use following TextInputLayout in your UI Layout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/usernameWrapper"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:hint="Username"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Than, call setHint on TextInputLayout just after setContentView call because, to animate the floating label, you just need to set a hint, using the setHint method.

```
final TextInputLayout usernameWrapper = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.usernameWrapper);
usernameWrapper.setHint("Username");
```

Comment: Using 23.1.1 at least, you don't need to use an explicit call to `setHint()`. It works with the hint set on the `EditText` in the layout xml.

Answer (score 3):

@andruboy's suggestion of https://gist.github.com/chrisbanes/11247418 is probably your best bet.

https://github.com/thebnich/FloatingHintEditText kind of works with appcompat-v7 v21.0.0, but since v21.0.0 does not support accent colors with subclasses of `EditText`, the underline of the `FloatingHintEditText` will be the default solid black or white. Also the padding is not optimized for the Material style `EditText`, so you may need to adjust it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm guessing google also has not provided an api for creating material-style edit text warning, like in http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/text-fields.html#text-fields-single-line-text-field

Sorry for the amateur questions, I'm trying to adapt to material design as much as I can using google's api/libraries and trying to figure out everything that has been provided vs any outside libraries. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

No it doesn't.  I would expect this in a future api release, but for now we are stuck with EditText.  Another option is this library:
https://github.com/marvinlabs/android-floatinglabel-widgets

Answer (score 0):

For an easier way to use the InputTextLayout, I have created this library that cuts your XML code to less than the half, and also provides you with the ability to set an error message as well as a hint message and an easy way to do your validations.
https://github.com/TeleClinic/SmartEditText

Simply add

```
compile 'com.github.TeleClinic:SmartEditText:0.1.0'
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
<com.teleclinic.kabdo.smartmaterialedittext.CustomViews.SmartEditText
    android:id="@+id/emailSmartEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:setLabel="Email"
    app:setMandatoryErrorMsg="Mandatory field"
    app:setRegexErrorMsg="Wrong email format"
    app:setRegexType="EMAIL_VALIDATION" />

<com.teleclinic.kabdo.smartmaterialedittext.CustomViews.SmartEditText
    android:id="@+id/passwordSmartEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:setLabel="Password"
    app:setMandatoryErrorMsg="Mandatory field"
    app:setPasswordField="true"
    app:setRegexErrorMsg="Weak password"
    app:setRegexType="MEDIUM_PASSWORD_VALIDATION" />

<com.teleclinic.kabdo.smartmaterialedittext.CustomViews.SmartEditText
    android:id="@+id/ageSmartEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:setLabel="Age"
    app:setMandatory="false"
    app:setRegexErrorMsg="Is that really your age :D?"
    app:setRegexString=".*\\d.*" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [**`TextInputLayout`**](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextField.md) provided by the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android):

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Label">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]