# TextInputLayout not showing EditText hint before user focus on it

Tags: android, material-design, android-design-library

I am using recently released [Android Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html) to show floating label with EditTexts. But i am facing the problem that the Hint on the EditText is not showing when UI is rendered, but i  see the Hint after i focus on the EditTexts.

My Layout is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/name_et_textinputlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FeedBackerNameET"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/feedbackname"
                    android:inputType="textPersonName|textCapWords" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/email_textinputlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/FeedBackerEmailET"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/feedbackemail"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <Spinner
                android:id="@+id/SpinnerFeedbackType"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="48dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:entries="@array/feedbacktypelist"
                android:prompt="@string/feedbacktype" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/body_textinputlayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <EditText
                    android:id="@+id/EditTextFeedbackBody"
                    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="@string/feedbackbody"
                    android:inputType="textMultiLine|textCapSentences"
                    android:lines="5" />

            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/CheckBoxFeedBackResponse"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="@string/feedbackresponse" />

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/ButtonSendFeedback"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:text="@string/feedbackbutton" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</FrameLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="5dp"
    android:background="@drawable/toolbar_shadow" />
</FrameLayout>
```

I have also tried to set hint for the `TextInputLayout` using method `setHint` but no luck.

```
mNameTextInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.name_et_textinputlayout);
mNameTextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
mNameTextInputLayout.setHint(feedBackerNameET.getHint());

mEmailTextInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.email_textinputlayout);
mEmailTextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
mEmailTextInputLayout.setHint(feedBackerEmail.getHint());

mBodyTextInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.body_textinputlayout);
mBodyTextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
mBodyTextInputLayout.setHint(feedBackBody.getHint());
```

Comment: I have the same problem. To my surprise running the application on 4.1 emulator worked just fine, but on my M preview enabled Nexus TextInputLayout was misbehaving and not showing the hint for the embedded EditText.

Comment: Can you check your hint color, or try to change your view background color, maybe they are there but you cant see because of color

Comment: @Ultimo_m i think hint color must not be problem. However i will try to have a look after changing the background color.

Comment: @Shajeel Afzal I am telling you this suggestion because I had the same problem as you, and when I added background to the view I saw the hint. I am using it inside a fragment. I didnt add any code from java, all I did is from xml

Comment: I'm seeing this issue when I add/remove fragments. But if I show/hide fragments, I don't see this issue.

Comment: Same problem with fragments, If I use add transaction works well when you go back. If I use replace transaction when you go back you dont see the hint

Answer (score 84, accepted):

**Update:**

This is a bug that has been fixed in version 22.2.1 of the library.

**Original Answer:**

As mentioned by @shkschneider, this is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175228). Github user @ljubisa987 recently posted a Gist for a workaround:

https://gist.github.com/ljubisa987/e33cd5597da07172c55d

As noted in the comments, the workaround only works on Android Lollipop and older. It does not work on the Android M Preview.

Comment: Well Android MDC is a preview version.

Comment: BTW, it looks like the bug status is now "Future Release."

Comment: As soon as the bug fixed is released, I'll update the answer. :-)

Comment: Comment #28 here: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175228&q=TextInputLayout&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars works for me

Comment: Fixed in version 22.2.1.

Comment: Can anyone confirm if the hint should be added to the EditText or the TextInputlayout? Both have the attribute.

Comment: Are we sure this is fixed in V22.2.1? I'm experiencing this issue in design library v22.2.1 running on Android version 5.1.1. I have two EditText in a Toolbar which I am Activity Transitioning to and the hint text isn't showing until focused.

Comment: The solution doesn't work on my Samsung Lollipop device.

Answer (score 13):

That is a [known bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=175228&q=TextInputLayout&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) of the Android Design library. It has been *accepted* and *assigned*.

So you should have this fixed in the next Android Design library release.

In the meantime, you could watch the issue tracker for a hacky-fix that might get posted there, but I don't know any as of now.

And yes, it only affect Lollipop and above.

Comment: This issue is fixed in version 22.2.1

Answer (score 13):

This works for me in Design Library 23.1.1:

Set the hint color in xml attributes of TextInputLayout:

```
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        ....
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:textColorHint="@color/hintColor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        ...
```

Comment: the textColorHint property fixed it for me as well.

Answer (score 6):

This issue is fixed in version 22.2.1

Answer (score 5):

you should use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText` as `EditText` and set `android:hint` like below

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/etx_first_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"                    
                android:inputType="text"
                android:hint="@string/hint_first_name"/>
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/editText1"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

              <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:hint="Add City" />

          </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Use this code snippet.Make sure your activity is AppCompatActivity.
And dependency are also with latest versions

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Update the android studio to latest version.
[see output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsx0Z.jpg)

Answer (score 3):

If you are setting your EditText hint programmatically it wouldn't work!
You need to set the hint on the TextInputLayout it self.

```
TextInputLayout textInputLayout = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.usernameTextInputLayout);
textInputLayout.setHint(getString(R.string.username_hint));
```

Here is the XML in case you are wondering:

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/usernameTextInputLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/usernameEt"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/default_height"
                android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/default_margin"
                android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/default_margin"
                android:maxLength="@integer/username"
                tools:hint="Username" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 3):

This issue is resolved in `v23.0.1` of support design library. I also updated my `appcompat-v7` to `23.0.1`, `compileSdkVersion` to `23` & `buildToolsVersion` to `23.0.1` in **build.gradle**.

```
android {    
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

Comment: Is it necessary to change compleSdkVersion,buildtools version and appCompatVersion when you are changing support design version??

Comment: It happens because the 'support libraries' v23 require the API23 to compile the project. So the main relation is between 'support libraries' and 'compileSdkVersion'. You should always match the 'compileSdkVersion' even if the 'targetSdkVersion' or 'minSdkVersion' are lower. The reason is  simple, version of the library reflects the version of the Android sdk against it was built.

Answer (score 2):

I solved my problem with this code:

```
new Handler().postDelayed(
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextInputLayout til = (TextInputLayout) someParentView.findViewById(R.id.til);
                til.setHint("Your Hint Text");
                til.bringToFront();
            }
        }, 10);
```

The key here is the `bringToFront`. It forces the `TextInputLayout` to redo its drawing, which is not the same as doing `invalidate()`. If you are trying to display the `TextInputLayout` on a `view` that has `animations` or `tranistions`, you need to execute the above code at the end of the `animation` or `transition`. Just make sure that the code above runs on the UI `thread`.

Answer (score 1):

Set hint color that contrast to the EditText background.

`<item name="android:textColorHint">#FF424242</item>`

Related:
[setHintTextColor() in EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6438478/1608670)
[Change EditText hint color when using TextInputLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30824009/1608670)
[How to change the floating label color of TextInputLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30546430/1608670)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this issue appears when you set onFousListener on EditText - try to extend EditText and support multiple onFocusListeners

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved:
Goto build.gradle of ur app and check design library. 
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
It should be 22.2.1 or newer.

Answer (score 0):

I found something different.

When setting the style for the `fragment`,

```
f1.setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME,android.R.style.Theme_DeviceDefault_Light);
```

The bug was gone when I tried different Styles than `"Theme_DeviceDefault_Dialog"`.

Give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is the hint color. It becomes white when typing something. Please change the hint color or change the background color. You will see the hint while typing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution to this as this worked for me

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/activity_login_til_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="27dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:passwordToggleEnabled="true"
    app:passwordToggleTint="#000000"
    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/passwordviewtoggleselector"
    android:theme="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat">
      <!---- add this line and theme as you need ----->
    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:id="@+id/activity_login_et_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="58dp"
        android:hint="Password"
        android:inputType="textPassword"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:textColor="#f5ab3a"
        android:textColorHint="#e6d2d1cf"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Just add **android:theme="@style/Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat"** to the TextEditLayout and it should work and you can change the theme as you need.

Answer (score 0):

Just add: `android:hint="your_hint"` for `TextInputLayout`.

Answer (score 0):

if you have set your layout background white please use it in your Activity Theme

```
 parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar"
```