# How can set TextInputLayout hintTextAppearance dynamically?

Tags: android, android-design-library

I want to create a new TextInputLayout dynamically by I must set `hintTextAppearance` to work correctly.

How can I set hintTextAppearance dynamically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change the floating label color of TextInputLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546430/how-to-change-the-floating-label-color-of-textinputlayout)

Answer (score 0):

hintTextAppearance will be same as you set Text Appearance of EditText.

Comment: editText.setHint does not solve my problem.
when i add a TextInputLayout the following error is ocurred:

Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:326) at android.support.design.widget.CollapsingTextHelper.setCollapsedTextAppearance(CollapsingTextHelper.java:166) 

set hintTextAppearance solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
        TextInputLayout textInput = findViewById(text input id);
        textInput.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.FloatingHintTextStyle);

       <style name="FloatingHintTextStyle" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
          <item name="android:textColor">@color/floating_hint_color</item>
       </style>
```