# Android changing TextInputLayout text color

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I want to change TextInputLayout float hint text. Here is the solution I tried:

style.xml:

```
<style name="TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
</style>
```

layout.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearence.App.TextInputLayout">
```

It works fine for some parts of app but not changes the hint color of some activities or fragments. I wonder How is it possible that a piece of code can effect some activities but not on the others.

Any idea?

Comment: look there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546430/how-to-change-the-floating-label-color-of-textinputlayout

Answer (score 2):

Add `<item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_color_blue</item>` line in your style.xml like this

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/theme_color_blue</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/theme_color_blue</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/colorTextPrimary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/colorTextSecondary</item>
</style>
```

Comment: It changes the bottom line color too

Comment: Then use <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/secondary_text</item>

Answer (score 1):

you should use textColorHint item for your AppTheme style:

```
<item name="android:textColorHint">@color/yourcolor</item>
```