# Change color of hint EditText - Android

Tags: android, android-edittext

Here i have the color of the hint that i want(Blue),photo nº1, but when i click it goes pink, phot nº2.
How can i change that to blue?
I have tried to change the hintColor but it does no good.`

```
<EditText
                android:id="@+id/password"
                android:backgroundTint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_password"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:imeActionId="@+id/login"
                android:imeActionLabel="@string/action_sign_in_short"
                android:imeOptions="actionUnspecified"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:singleLine="true" />`
```

[Photo 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YBLhZ.png)

[Photo 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gk3FS.png%C2%B4)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the floating label color of TextInputLayout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546430/how-to-change-the-floating-label-color-of-textinputlayout)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For those who want to know the answer after the comments.
Just put this on the style.xml file.
Thx a lot

```
<item name="colorAccent">@android:color/holo_blue_dark</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with direct color code something like this

```
android:textColorHint="#4C33FF"
```

Answer (score 0):

try `TextInputLayout` :

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
android:textColorHint="#F7B7C2"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myid"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:hint="something"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**Update:**

Change your "colorAccent" in your `Apptheme` in `styles.xml` file with the color you need

Comment: already tried...
It does not work it seems to be affecting the word when it is on the line not when it on the top(when i click the line)

Comment: my guess is that your:  "colorAccent" is pink, try first change it to blue or whatever.. and let me know

Comment: it does not work i'll out the code:

 <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColorHint="@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                android:colorAccent = "@android:color/holo_blue_dark"
                >

Comment: no, i mean  "colorAccent"  in your `Apptheme` in styles.xml file