# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2

Tags: java, android

This exception is only thrown when inflating EditText on two ASUS smartphones (Asus Zenfone 5 - API 19 and Asus Zenfone 2 - API 21). Other devices/emulators work fine.

### Full stack trace:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package.example/com.package.example.activity.SignUpActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class EditText
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2318)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2396)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:139)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1293)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:149)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5257)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:793)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:609)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
arrow_drop_down
Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #47: Error inflating class EditText
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:713)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:755)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:758)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:758)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:758)
android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:839)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:745)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:492)
uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate (CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:397)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:353)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:143)
com.package.example.activity.SignUpActivity.onCreate (SignUpActivity.java:88)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5411)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1087)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2270)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2396)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:139)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1293)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:149)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5257)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:793)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:609)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
arrow_drop_down
Caused by java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x2
android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor (TypedArray.java:327)
android.widget.TextView.<init> (TextView.java:700)
android.widget.EditText.<init> (EditText.java:61)
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init> (AppCompatEditText.java:62)
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText.<init> (AppCompatEditText.java:58)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView (AppCompatViewInflater.java:112)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1017)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1076)
android.support.v4.view.LayoutInflaterCompatHC$FactoryWrapperHC.onCreateView (LayoutInflaterCompatHC.java:44)
uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater$WrapperFactory2.onCreateView (CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:280)
android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag (LayoutInflater.java:684)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:755)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:758)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:758)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:758)
android.view.LayoutInflater.parseInclude (LayoutInflater.java:839)
android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate (LayoutInflater.java:745)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:492)
uk.co.chrisjenx.calligraphy.CalligraphyLayoutInflater.inflate (CalligraphyLayoutInflater.java:60)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:397)
android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate (LayoutInflater.java:353)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView (AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView (AppCompatActivity.java:143)
com.package.example.activity.SignUpActivity.onCreate (SignUpActivity.java:88)
android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:5411)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1087)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2270)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2396)
android.app.ActivityThread.access$800 (ActivityThread.java:139)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1293)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:149)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5257)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative (Method.java)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:515)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:793)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:609)
dalvik.system.NativeStart.main (NativeStart.java)
```

### Layout

```
        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            app:errorTextAppearance="@style/AppTheme.Error"
            app:hintEnabled="true"
            app:theme="@style/AppTheme.TextInput.White">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/nickname"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/prompt_username"
                android:inputType="textPersonName"
                android:maxLines="1" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

### Theme

```
<style name="AppTheme.TextInput.White" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/whiteC</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/whiteC</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/whiteC</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/whiteC</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!--Error-->
<style name="AppTheme.Error" parent="AppTheme.Text.White">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
</style>
```

Thing I tried already:

- Replacing TextInputEditText with EditText
- Removing textColor="@color/white" from EditText
- Downgrading to support library 24,23. (Currently I'm on 25.0.1)

Comment: Have you tried commenting out the colors in your style definition for the EditText, and then one by one adding them back in until one of them breaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546430/how-to-change-the-floating-label-color-of-textinputlayout#comment62371700_30914037) problem is solved by changing parent of text input layout's theme to `ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light`:

```
<style name="AppTheme.TextInput.White" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/whiteC</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHighlight">@color/whiteC</item>
    <item name="android:textColorLink">@color/whiteC</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/whiteC</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<!--Error-->
<style name="AppTheme.Error" parent="AppTheme.Text.White">
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">italic</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same exception but the reason is quiet different than the OP issue, it only appears below API level 21. And the reason is of using `ShapeableImageView` in layout; I have no special attributes in it, but once using normal `ImageView`, the exception is gone.

This is `ShapeableImageView` I was using:

```
<com.google.android.material.imageview.ShapeableImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:padding="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/btn_change"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```