# Layout Inflation with TextInputLayout slow

Tags: android

I have a Custom View which is extends from `LinearLayout`.
In the `init{}` I call the `inflate` function to inflate my layout.

```
inflate(context, R.layout.base_layout, this)
```

I logged the inflating speed, like this:

```
// Log.
inflate(context, R.layout.base_layout, this)
// Log
```

It takes `1ms` to inflate the layout. Awesome!
But when my layout have a TextInputLayout than it increases to `120ms`

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/randomName2"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/randomName"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/randomName4"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:paddingTop="8dp">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
                android:id="@+id/randomName3"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="text" />

        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/randomName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/randomName2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/randomName2"/>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

How can I fix this `120ms` issue? This creates FPS lag when my fragment creating.

Thank you for any suggestion.

Comment: Would you try with using `EditText` instead of `TextInputLayout`?

Comment: Really!, I need to use it, but it's still 120 ms

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41177588/textinputlayout-floating-label-appears-slow

Comment: If I can then I try to find another solution. But maybe for last option, I'll try. thank you