# Input Layout toggle hintText color change

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using `TextInputLayout` in which i want to change the color of `hinttext`  when i enter text then the color of hint text should be blue other wise color should be gray and when `edittext` contains some value then the color of `hintText` should blue for more information please check my image.

[image: image1]

Ultimate i want this after edit text containing some value.

[image: image2]

This is my current result after using this code

[image: image3]

```
  <style name="labelcolor" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <!-- Hint color and label color in FALSE state -->
    <item name="android:textColorHint">#868686</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
    <item name="android:paddingTop">5sp</item>
    <!-- Label color in TRUE state and bar color FALSE and TRUE State -->
    <item name="colorAccent">#0ea3ff</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">#0ea3ffr</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">#0ea3ff</item>
</style>
```

please help me how can i solve this issues.

Comment: Once you start typing hint text will not visible, so you cant change the color of hint text. you can change the color of text that you have entered.

Comment: I have to change label color of email.

Comment: check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30914037/1993001

Comment: i have used this things only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change TextInputLayout Lebel Color Dynamicaly in on Focus change of edittext and pass color according work for me.

```
 public static void textInoutLayoutColor(TextInputLayout textInputLayout, @ColorInt int color) {

    try {
        Field fDefaultTextColor = TextInputLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mDefaultTextColor");
        fDefaultTextColor.setAccessible(true);
        fDefaultTextColor.set(textInputLayout, new ColorStateList(new int[][]{{0}}, new int[]{ color }));

        Field fFocusedTextColor = TextInputLayout.class.getDeclaredField("mFocusedTextColor");
        fFocusedTextColor.setAccessible(true);
        fFocusedTextColor.set(textInputLayout, new ColorStateList(new int[][]{{0}}, new int[]{ color }));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and change the color like this.

```
input_layout= (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout);
   etuser_name.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean hasfocus) {
            if(hasfocus){
                textInoutLayoutColor(input_layout,getResources().getColor(R.color.bullet_color));
            }
            else
            {
                if(etuser_name.getText().toString().trim().length()>0) {
                    textInoutLayoutColor(input_layout,getResources().getColor(R.color.bullet_color));;
                }
                else
                {
                    textInoutLayoutColor(input_layout,getResources().getColor(R.color.hint_grey));
                }
            }
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Create your as bellow and try

```
<style name="EditTextHint" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorAccent">@android:color/white</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
    <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/your color</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/BackgroundtWhiteColor</item>
</style>
```

Use it as bellow

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:theme="@style/EditTextHint"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
      <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to set your TextInputLayout

```
 android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout textInputLayout =        (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.textInputLayout);

textInputLayout.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.Instyle);
```

and then in styles.xml file you can create your styles with the color for the hint color.

```
<style name="Instyle" parent="AppThemeLight">
    <itemname="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/darker_gray</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

TextInputLayout takes `colorAccent` to hintTextColor when you start entering values in edittext. 
So if you want it to be blue then set your `colorAccent` to blue colour in your theme. And when edittext has no value then set hintTextColor to `grey`. Do like this

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/userNameTIL"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="55dp"
                    android:background="@color/spinnerBg"
                    android:clipToPadding="false"
                    android:gravity="bottom"
                    android:paddingTop="4dp"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/grey"> /*Here it sets color to hintText when edittext has no value */

                    <EditText
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="50dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
                        android:background="@null"
                        android:hint="Username"
                        android:inputType="text"
                        android:maxLength="30"
                        android:paddingEnd="3dp"
                        android:paddingStart="25dp"
                        android:paddingTop="3dp"
                        android:singleLine="true"
                        android:textColor="@color/black"
                        android:textColorHint="@color/black"
                        android:textSize="20sp"/>
                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
                <!--EditText hint color-->
                <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/default_app_white</item>             <!-- TextInputLayout text color-->
                <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/default_app_green</item>
                <!-- EditText line color when EditText on-focus-->
                <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/default_app_green</item>
                <!-- EditText line color when EditText  in un-focus-->
                <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/default_app_white</item>
            </style>
 <!-- In your style.xml file -->
```

try this one but it affects your whole application