# clicking on TextInputLayout crashes in Oppo F1S running 5.1.1

Tags: android, android-layout, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

After clicking on TextInputLayout, the app crashes after a delay of 1 sec in Oppo F1S running 5.1.1. I dont have access to device fist I got crash reported by crashlytics, then I asked my remote friends to try it on their oppo phone.

I am not able to figure out the cause, and again as I dont have access to the device, I am finding its very difficuilt to counter the issue.

Its working fine in other devices and even in oppoF7 which is running 8.1.0

**This is my XML**

```
   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/til_email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
            android:theme="@style/TextLabel"
            app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView53">

            <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                android:id="@+id/et_email"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#00000000"
                android:drawablePadding="10dp"
                android:hint="Email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:onTextChanged="@{(text, start, before, count) -> activity.onEmailChanged(text)}"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/black" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

**This is styles.xml**

```
<!--Input field style-->
    <style name="MyEditText" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/greish</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/black</item>
    </style>
    <style name="ErrorText" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold|italic</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat">



 <style name="TextAppearance.App.TextInputLayout" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/greish</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
    </style>
```

**Stacktrace 1**

```
Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class TextView
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:763)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
   at android.widget.OppoCursorController$FloatPanelViewController.<init>(OppoCursorController.java:1585)
   at android.widget.OppoCursorController.createFloatPanelViewController(OppoCursorController.java:134)
   at android.widget.OppoCursorController$SelectionModifierCursorController.<init>(OppoCursorController.java:518)
   at android.widget.OppoCursorController.create(OppoCursorController.java:81)
   at android.widget.OppoEditor.getOppoSelectionController(OppoEditor.java:417)
   at android.widget.OppoEditor.onTouchEventWrap(OppoEditor.java:322)
   at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8189)
   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8472)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2440)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1748)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2840)
   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2379)
   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8667)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4446)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4234)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3767)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3830)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3786)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3913)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3794)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3970)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3767)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3830)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3786)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3794)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3767)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6165)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6139)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6110)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6255)
   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:218)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:150)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

**Stacktrace 2:**

```
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to resolve attribute at index 24
   at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:401)
   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:709)
   at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:645)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:75)
   at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView.<init>(AppCompatTextView.java:71)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:103)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.createView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1024)
   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:1081)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:725)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:806)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:809)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:504)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:414)
   at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
   at android.widget.OppoCursorController$FloatPanelViewController.<init>(OppoCursorController.java:1585)
   at android.widget.OppoCursorController.createFloatPanelViewController(OppoCursorController.java:134)
   at android.widget.OppoCursorController$SelectionModifierCursorController.<init>(OppoCursorController.java:518)
   at android.widget.OppoCursorController.create(OppoCursorController.java:81)
   at android.widget.OppoEditor.getOppoSelectionController(OppoEditor.java:417)
   at android.widget.OppoEditor.onTouchEventWrap(OppoEditor.java:322)
   at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:8189)
   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8472)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2417)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2050)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2440)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1748)
   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2840)
   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchTouchEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:68)
   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2379)
   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8667)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4446)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4234)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3767)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3830)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3786)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3913)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3794)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3970)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3767)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3830)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3786)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3794)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3767)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6165)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:6139)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6110)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:6255)
   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:218)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(MessageQueue.java)
   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:150)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5541)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:964)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:759)
```

**Any Idea what might be the problem?** (I don't have access to the device, I got stacktrace from crashlytics)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: use  android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText  Instead of Edittext  and dont use android:onclick="" attribute with it, it will crash on lollypop devices,  some wired compatibility bug

Comment: in xml, right? Here you already used it in your xml and still got error.

Comment: yeah in xml,  I have 3 textinputLayouts, the crash was not due to above xml it was another textInputlayout in same xml

Comment: did you find any solution for that

Comment: were you able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: For `Fatal Exception: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #42: Error inflating class TextView` check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/30914037/7666442 (read comments)

Answer (score 3):

Use `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText` Instead of `Edittext` and dont use `android:onclick` attribute with it, it will crash on lolipop devices.

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem on some. In my case the solution was to put the `hint` in the `TextInputLayout` and **NOT** in the `EditText`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is `Failed to resolve attribute at index 24`; caused by:

```
<style name="MyEditText" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

a) this has to be replaced with a style, which inherits `Widget.Design.TextInputLayout`:

```
<style name="MyEditText" parent="Widget.Design.TextInputLayout">
```

b) or use `com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout`, as [explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54385942/how-to-make-textview-which-is-under-edit-text-is-pushed-up-with-keyboard-showi/54386004#54386004); this would need a matching style, which inherits `Base.Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout`.

always inherit the style which comes with the component, to avoid such issues.