# TextInputEditText change theme dynamically

Tags: android, android-edittext, styles, themes

How to change theme of EditText (TextInputEditText) programmatically in Android.

Comment: refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546430/how-to-change-the-floating-label-color-of-textinputlayout?answertab=votes#tab-top

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change the floating label color of TextInputLayout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546430/how-to-change-the-floating-label-color-of-textinputlayout)