# How to set colorControlActivated for TextInputLayout in programmatically

Tags: android, kotlin, material-design, android-textinputlayout, material-components-android

How to set colorControlActivated for TextInputLayout in programmatically ?

because i want to set underline color. and my color is string (#....) not in R.color
thanks!

Comment: go for this link you will get help , :https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30546430/how-to-change-the-floating-label-color-of-textinputlayout

Comment: Gabriele's answer looks good, but note that `colorControlActivated` is a _theme attribute_, and so you have to _create_ the widget with a theme that has the attribute set. Once the widget is created, there's no way to change that value.

Answer (score 1):

With the [`TextInputLayout`](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/TextInputLayout.md) included in the [Material Components Library](https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android) you can use the method:

```
textInputLayout.setBoxStrokeColor(..)
```

With a FilledBox style which is the default style `(Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.FilledBox`) the underline color is the strokeColor.

In xml you can use `app:boxStrokeColor`.

[image]

You should use a selector. The default value is something like:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:color="@color/colorPrimary" android:state_focused="true"/>
  <!-- 4% overlay over 42% colorOnSurface -->
  <item android:alpha="0.46" android:color="@color/colorOnSurface" android:state_hovered="true"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.38" android:color="@color/colorOnSurface" android:state_enabled="false"/>
  <item android:alpha="0.42" android:color="@color/colorOnSurface"/>
</selector>
```