# Android TextInputField Inflator Error

Tags: android, android-design-library

Had a crash while trying to use the new `TextInputField` for Android and wanted to share my solution.

Trying the new TextInputField in the android appcompat library was crashing my app.  Here was my layout xml.

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="e-mail"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:singleLine="true"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

The error I got:

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #20: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout.
```

SOLUTION:
Add the `hintTextAppearance` attribute to your `TextInputLayout`, so the lead tag looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
```

Comment: Your solution worked, thanks!

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Make sure you have the following dependencies in your gradle file:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

Working example:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/txtEmail_InpLyt"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtEmail"
        android:hint="Email Address"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

(Setting `hintTextAppearance` is not necessary.)

**Update:**

If you experience issues with the hint text not appearing in newer versions of Android (Marshmallow / Nougat), update library to version 22.2.1 (see [TextInputLayout not showing EditText hint before user focus on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537413/textinputlayout-not-showing-edittext-hint-before-user-focus-on-it)).

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'
```

Comment: This works, but I was really surprised that to get the TextInputLayout to work properly you have to add another library.  Seems poorly done.

Comment: compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.0.1'
   compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.1'
}

Comment: @GilSnovsky i have updated my libraries but some of my app users (android api level 23 )are still getting this frustrating error `Caused by android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #17: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`

Comment: It works for me, however you may need to: Build -> Clean Project, then rebuild/run again.

Answer (score 24):

This happened to me as well, and I came up with a solution that does not require changing the App Theme, but merely changing the Theme of the TextInputLayout:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/testingInputLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/testingEditText"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:hint="@string/testText"
       android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

You will need to add the appCompat library if you have not already:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
```

Answer (score 19):

in adroidx it worked for me
i have the libraries

```
 implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    //design widget
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

i change

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

for

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
```

Comment: Perfect. Guys this is the right answer at this time of the year b.c the reason it keeps crashing is b.c support library changed from android to androidx

Comment: Also you can change support design dependency to :implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0-alpha02' now suported on androidx

Answer (score 4):

I got the same issue when inflating XML containing `TextInputLayout`.
The problem was fixed by setting the correct Style on my application. Just like it says here : [android design support library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711813/android-design-support-library-with-theme-material)

I've the following issue

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
```

My style.xml was

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Material">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

As it said in [this post on Design Support Library](http://android-developers.blogspot.ca/2015/05/android-design-support-library.html)

> Note that as the Design library depends on the Support v4 and AppCompat Support Libraries, those will be included automatically when you add the Design library dependency.

So NO NEED TO ADD the following line inside the gradle file

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
```

I found the link behove explaining that the Design Support Library is part of the AppCompat and it require the AppCompat Theme base to work. So
I've modify my style.xml to be

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

And it worked.

Comment: It's not clear which part of the question you linked is *"setting the correct Style"*.  Can you show what you mean with a quick sample, like a line of code/config?  (It's best practice to summarize a link anyways, just in case its target changes :)

Comment: -1 It might work but what is the use of using support library if you add parent="android:Theme.Material" you have to change the api to 21. @pierre

Answer (score 2):

just to be clear as of `Android Studio 3.*` this is now changed to

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

(if this goes red a squiggly when you add it *accept* the version Android Studio wants to suggest)

this needs to be inside the

```
 dependencies {}
```

section of `build.gradle (Module:app)` so it looks like this

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
}
```

then hit `sync now`

Answer (score 1):

Use the following:

```
View view = LayoutInflator.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.your_layout_file,parent,false);
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the LayoutInflater is created from an AppCompatActivity

ex.

instead of

```
inflater = (LayoutInflater)ctx.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
```

use:

```
inflater = LayoutInflater.from(<appCompatActivity>);
```

Answer (score 1):

None of the solution worked for me. I am using

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Tried all the soluton. My app runs perfectly in devices with lower sdk. But crashes in newer( greater than sdk 26) devices. But after scratching head for 2 days finally got the solution.

my layout editor showed the error of

`The following classes could not be instantiated:
    - android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout`

[image]
But it did not gave me enough information to work with. It was not until I looked at other errors at the layout editor. Under render problem I found that

```
Couldn't resolve resource @string/path_password_strike_through
```

[image]

I finally got the solution after investigating this render problem. All you need to do is add

```
app:passwordToggleDrawable="@string/string_name"
```

in your TextInputLayout xml file.

```
                <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                    android:id="@+id/login_input_layout_password"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    app:passwordToggleDrawable="@drawable/ic_lock_outline_grey600_24dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
                    app:boxStrokeColor="#555"
                    android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/login_input_password"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        />

                </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got this working...as per as the latest changes in the library itself, change the library from

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt_input"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edt_first_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:hintEnabled="false">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Floating Hint Disabled" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

to

```
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/txt_input"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/edt_first_name"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/guideline"
        app:hintEnabled="false">

        <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Floating Hint Disabled" />

    </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you might have added it
`compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'` but you need to add `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`

you can try this dependencies:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
```

in your gradle file.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with Android Studio 3.0.1

All you need to add the following line into **gradle.properties (Project Propeties)**:

> android.enableAapt2=false

Comment: #UPDATE :
Change the layout theme, where TextInputField is defined.

Example: (in my case, I used TextInputField in activity_main.xml
so it will be like:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout ....
:::::
android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

--> AppTheme should be a child of Theme.AppCompat or Decendent

Answer (score 0):

for me work changes from EditText to TextInputEditText

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/date_raffle"/>

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0' all you have to do is use your XML tags like this: <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout for it to work...In my case it applies to my <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText as well. Happy coding!...