# Error inflating TextInputLayout when used with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-textinputlayout

Looks like `TextInputLayout` just doesn't work inside `ViewPager`.

The error is:

> Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

`Appcompat` and `Design library` added. `Theme` is correct.

I use `PageAdapter` to inflate and populate `ViewPager`.

The `TextInputLayout` view **inflates just fine** in all other parts of the application.

The `layout` I inflate for the `ViewPager`.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content">

  <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
      android:id="@+id/edit_text"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:hint="My Edit Text" />

  </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711813/android-design-support-library-with-theme-material

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya, the View inflates anywhere else but `ViewPager` so it's not a theme, a libraries or anything.

Comment: What's the entire logcat? Which exception is it throwing? Or is that a "preview" error?

Comment: Kindly post detailed error in logcat!

Comment: @KevinChris the stack trace is absolutely not informative, a regular exception a View can't be inflated.

Comment: @Eugene did you find a solution for this ?

Comment: Hey, did you resolved the issue ? I am facing similar issue and none of below solutions work for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
```

you have also to extend your class with AppCompatActivity instead of Activity

Answer (score 0):

You should try a few things to fix the problem.

- extend your activity from AppCompatActivity
- extend your (dialog)fragment from android.support.v4.app.Fragment.
- use latest version of design library.
- Instead of using EditText, use android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText. For example:

  ```
      <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      app:errorEnabled="true">

                      <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
                          android:layout_width="match_parent"
                          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                          android:hint="First Name"
                          android:inputType="textPersonName"
                          android:singleLine="true" />

      </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
  ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and none of the above solutions worked for me. Finally, I switched **PagerAdapter** to **FragmentStatePagerAdapter** and implemented the whole thing with *Fragment*.

You can refer to [this link](https://www.sitepoint.com/material-design-android-design-support-library/) for the reference.

For my experiment, I tweaked the demo and inserted **TextInputLayout** inside it's **ViewPager** and everything worked perfectly.