# Runtime error when using by Fragment with TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-support-library

My Code xml:

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/home_header"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"/>

    <TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:hintTextAppearance="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium"
        android:id="@+id/textInputLayout_carRegNumber">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText_carRegNumber"
            />
    </TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I am using the above layout in a Fragment class and the error I am getting is;

```
     android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #25: Error inflating class TextInputLayout
```

I know my class should extend AppCompatActivity but I am working with Fragment because I am using Tabs from the support design library. How can I work with TextInputLayout inside Fragment class?

Comment: Which theme are you using??

Comment: i guess its your theme problem .Have a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711813/android-design-support-library-with-theme-material  And http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30958972/inflateexception-with-textinputlayout-and-alertdialog

Comment: My parent theme is Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar

Comment: The thing is everything is working right I have even implemented  toolbar and a Tab but now since I am working with view pager I need to use TextInputLayout in one of the fragment class but I end up with the error

Comment: have you found any solution to this?