# Cannot use TextInputLayout in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-textinputlayout

I cannot seem to be able to use TextInputLayout in fragment. Here is my code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".LoginFragment">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/email_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputEditText
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="email"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:maxLines="1" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

When I try to run I get this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout"
```

I red this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30711813/android-design-support-library-with-theme-material) which says I should use `AppCompat Theme` and I am using `AppCompat Theme`

Here is my Theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Do you have the support design library in your build.gradle file?

Comment: I added `support:support-v4` library, apparently I should have added `support:design` library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding this dependency to gradle solved the problem

```
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
```

Comment: without this line, it also cannot work with an Activity