# Android Error inflating class TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-design-library

I'm trying to use `TextInputLayout` in my XML, and I'm meeting this error :

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{fr.jechange.moncompte/fr.jechange.moncompte.SignUpActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
[...]
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #36: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
[...]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Landroid/support/design/R$styleable;
```

I've imported the design library, and the `support-v7-appcompat` library. And I'm using the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` theme.

The XML in which I'm using the *Text Input Layout* contains just something like that:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:res="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
style="@style/matchParent">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <EditText
            android:inputType="text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Make sure you have v7 jar file in lib folder.

Comment: I tried but nothing. But currently, I linked my project with the support-v7-appcompat library, so I don't need to add v7 jar ? (I've always a problem with library, jar, etc.)

Comment: When we link a lib it automatically adds into lib directory but sometimes it does not. So we have to do that manually.

Comment: Ok, so in my case the v7 jar wasn't added to my projet. But I added it manually, and it doesn't solve my problem :/

Comment: which IDE are u using?

Comment: I think u should create a test project and try using that class. if still problem persists then u have problem in sdk, you might be missing some support lib.

Comment: I already tried to delete all libs / jars, and to re import them, but doesn't work :/

Comment: Switch to Android studio first

Answer (score 1):

if you are calling layout(containg TextInputLayout) from activity then
nothing just use YouActivityClassName.this in place of getApplicationcontext or YourApplicationClassName.getcontext() or other where you are passing context

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue fixed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30578976/android-textinputfield-inflator-error/31415581#31415581).
Make sure you don't have any other support library import v4 and v7. You can use only the design-support library. Also you should make sure your theme "matchParent" inherit from Theme.AppCompat for all the platform you trying to run.
My issue was only on Lollipop because of the `values-21/style.xml`.

Hope it will help.

Comment: Nop it was fine... After few restart of eclipse for others reasons, it works... lol...

Comment: my style inherit `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar` hope that is ok