# In Android, how can I use TextInputLayout and Snackbar without the Design Support Library

Tags: android, material-design

I am developing a new Android project with a minimum SDK set at 5.0. I want to use material design, but it seems like many of the material design components are only included in the support library. I really want to theme the app as Material, not AppCompat.

When I try to add a layout from the support library, I get an error every time. What do I need to do to remove the support library dependencies?

Comment: You can't. Those components are part of the supports design lib and not of the SDK. You have to build each widget yourself if you don't want the design lib.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Snackbar is only available in the design support library - it is not baked into versions of Android like EditText/ImageView views.

Comment: So do I need to set the Theme to AppCompat, or can I use Material?

Comment: Which theme you use should be independent of whether you want to use the Design Support Library widgets. Although an advantage of using the support library is that you're more likely to have a consistent experience on different API levels.

Comment: Thanks! Using what you said about not needing to change themes, and doing some more digging, I was able to figure out that I could theme individual views for AppCompat (see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32891389/763080)) and it solved my problems!