# EditText hint not showing in Lollipop with android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-5.0-lollipop, android-textinputlayout

I am using TabLayout and in TabLayout's fragment there are some Edit-text boxes. I am using android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout for hint animations.

Application work perfectly up-to ver. 4.4 but from 5.0.1(Lollipop) Hints of Edittext boxes are disappear and only shown after focus on Edit-text.

These are the Screenshots :- 
 1. Screenshot in lollipop when fragment created
 2. Screenshot in lollipop after focus on edittext
 3. Screenshot of pre-Lollipop device.

[image: screenshot in lollipop when fragment created]

[image: Screenshot in lollipop after focus on EditText]

[image: Screenshot of Pre-Lollipop Device]

Comment: Share your code, not screenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TextInputLayout not showing EditText hint before user focus on it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537413/textinputlayout-not-showing-edittext-hint-before-user-focus-on-it)