# EditText getHint() returns null when using design support library

Tags: android, android-edittext, androiddesignsupport

When using EditText in combination with Design lib's (ver 22.2.1) TextInputLayout getting hint programmatically returns null.

I'm trying to append asterisk '*' to a mandatory field programmatically, hence `EditText.getHint()` but the fact that it returns null is an issue in this case.

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);
String hint = String.format("%s *", editText.getHint());
editText.setHint(hint);
```

[image: Asterisk overlays the hint]

A simple code illustration:
Layout.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="@string/hello_world"
            android:inputType="text"/>
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Java:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit2);
if (editText.getHint() == null) throw new AssertionError("Hint should not be null");
```

dependency: compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'

Previously related issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537413/textinputlayout-not-showing-edittext-hint-before-user-focus-on-it)!

Comment: There are [many hint-related issues with `TextInputLayout`](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=1&q=TextInputLayout+hint&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Owner+Summary+Stars&cells=tiles). You might consider trying [other floating label implementations](http://android-arsenal.com/search?q=floating+label).

Comment: Well issue is obviously setHint() as well as it does not reflect on the hint previously configured on the TextInputLayout

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Actually the hint moves to the parent view `TextInputLayout` that surrounds the `EditText` view:

You can get the hint like this:

```
android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout parent = (android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout) yourEditText.getParent();
String hint = parent.getHint().toString();
```

And if you want to add `*` make it like this:

```
parent.setHint(parent.getHint() + "*");
```

Happy codding! :)

Comment: Note that if you are using `TextInputEditText` as is recommended you have to use `getParent().getParent()` to actually get the `TextInputLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Hint is linked with its's parent layout

> ((TextInputLayout)view.getParent()).getHint()

Answer (score 0):

Simply you need to target the `TextInputLayout` instead of the `EditText`, I'm using [Material Design](https://material.io/components/text-fields/android#filled-text-field)

```xml
<com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputLayoutFirstName"
    ...>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
        ...
        android:hint="First Name"/>
</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

So basically to change the hint try:

```kotlin
inputLayoutFirstName.apply {
    hint = hint.toString().plus("*")
}
```

You can also have this extension:

```kotlin
private fun TextInputLayout.addRequiredSymbolHint() {
    hint = hint.toString().plus("*")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using in the kotlin

```
((edittext.parent as FrameLayout).parent as TextInputLayout).hint
```

and you can add that code to extension class as

```
fun EditText.findHint(): String {
    ((this.parent as FrameLayout).parent as TextInputLayout).hint?.let { 
        return  it.toString()
    }?: kotlin.run { return "" }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is fixed in design support `23.0.0` but the project has to be compiled for api `23`.

**build.gradle**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion '23'
    ....
}
dependencies{
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
...
}
```

Setting the hint on the `EditText` like before:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/inputField"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hello_world"
        android:inputType="text"/>
```

Now adding an extra character to the hint:

```
TextInputLayout inputField = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.inputLayout);
String hint = String.format("%s *", inputField.getHint());
inputField.setHint(hint);
```

Comment: This is not fixed in 23.0.0

Comment: The issue with declaring the hint in TextInputLayout is that hint value is not showing unless set programmatically (like in the example). But eventually moving the hint to edit text worked. Will update the answer, feel free to verify.

Comment: The question's issue is about the TextInputLayout's EditText's hint returning null. I verified that this issue still exists in v 23 of the library. Even when setting the hint on the TextInputLayout, the hint still returns null.