# Programmatically get hint text value in android Edittext

Tags: java, android

I have to change the`Typeface` of `EditText`  dynamically and also process the hint text if the Typeface changed. I simply do as following:

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_textBox"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textBox"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="@string/hint_date" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

And my code snippet is as follow:

```
EditText textBox = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.textBox);
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(this, "myfont.ttf");
textBox.setTypeface(tf);
String hintText = textBox.getHint().toString(); //Got NullPointerException here....
String newText = processText(hintText); //This will process the hint text;
textBox.setHint(newText);
```

When I runt the program, I got the following exception:

`java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.String java.lang.CharSequence.toString()' on a null object reference`

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: have you tried getParent().getHint()? You're probably using the design support lib.

Comment: @Anix PasBeson there is no getParent().getHint() in EditText.

Comment: Post your xml plz.

Comment: @Anix PasBeson, I have edited my xml code snippet.

Comment: @Anix PasBesoin. Yes, I have tried and it's ok now. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

We need to look at `your_layout.xml` first to determine that, but you're probably using the design support lib.

If so, you can get your hints as follows:

```
((TextInputLayout)textBox.getParent()).getHint();
```

## Note

This has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725241/edittext-gethint-returns-null-when-using-design-support-library). (Although we needed to make sure that you were using the design support lin to mark your question as duplicate)