# TextInputLayout error after enter value into edittext

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout

How can i hide a `TextInputLayout` error after input one text in `EditText`.
Is it possible?

how can i achieve this or I am doing something wrong here.!!

[image]

**code**

```
    layoutEdtPhone =(TextInputLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.layoutEdtPhone);
    layoutEdtPhone.setErrorEnabled(true);
    layoutEdtPhone.setError(getString(R.string.ui_no_phone_toast));
    layoutEdtPassword =   (TextInputLayout)rootView.findViewById(R.id.layoutEdtPassword);
    layoutEdtPassword.setErrorEnabled(true);
    layoutEdtPassword.setError(getString(R.string.ui_no_password_toast));

    edtPhone=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtPhone);
    edtPassword=(EditText)rootView.findViewById(R.id.edtPassword);
```

**xml**

```
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtPhone"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edt_background_selector"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/phone_icon"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/phone_icon"
                android:hint="@string/phone"
                android:inputType="phone"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

        <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/layoutEdtPassword"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/edtPassword"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@drawable/edt_background_selector"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/password_icon"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/password_icon"
                android:hint="@string/password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:padding="5dip"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:textSize="14sp" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: can you post total code

Comment: i think you are using fragment

Comment: which version you using ? buildToolsVersion

Comment: sorry for late.  i have used 5.1.1 22 latest one and yes its fragment

Comment: taka a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537413/textinputlayout-not-showing-edittext-hint-before-user-focus-on-it

Answer (score 25, accepted):

To illustrate further the answer given by Prithviraj, `TextInputLayout` does not do the validation itself. It is just a mechanism to show the error or hint. You are responsible for setting/clearing the error. Here is how you can do that. Note that in addition to TextChangedListener, you may also need OnFocusChangeListener to set the error when user jumps to second edit text without doing any modification in the first field.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        //.....

        edtPhone.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                validateEditText(s);
            }
        });

        edtPhone.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus) {
                    validateEditText(((EditText) v).getText());
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void validateEditText(Editable s) {
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(s)) {
            layoutEdtPhone.setError(null);
        }
        else{
            layoutEdtPhone.setError(getString(R.string.ui_no_password_toast));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks its working but i wanted without textwatcher, something like its own attribute.

Comment: Unfortunately, Android does not support validation using attributes. However, there are 2 libraries which may help you reduce some code related to validation. You can check them out here: http://v.zasadnyy.com/blog/android-form-validation-right-way/

Comment: What if I have 10 EditText?

Comment: Creating a custom class that extends TextInputLayout is the way to go. Check my answer

Answer (score 11):

You can set `layoutEdtPhone.setErrorEnabled(false);`

Answer (score 7):

Do

```
mTextInputLayout.setError(null);
```

to clear the error message.

A good practice can be a method to check for errors like this:

```
@Override
public void checkErrorBeforeAction() {

    boolean error = false;

    mTextInputLayout.setError(null);

    if (mEditText.getText().toString().length == 0)) {
        mTextInputLayout.setError("Field empty");
    }
    else if (mEditText.getText().toString().isValid) { // Other condition
        mTextInputLayout.setError("Field is invalid");
    }
    if (!error) {
        // Call action
    }
}
```

This way it refreshes the error message before setting a new one.

Answer (score 6):

I used @TextChanged of [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) and worked for me, look:

```
@Bind(R.id.layoutEdtPhone)
TextInputLayout tlayoutEdtPhone;
@Bind(R.id.edtPhone)
EditText edtPhone;

//start ButterKnife (I spent the URL with full description for initilize)

@OnTextChanged(R.id.edtPhone)
public void changedTextOnEditPhone() {
    tlayoutEdtPhone.setError("");
}
```

If you want know about ButterKnife, I wrote a post with more detail, but it was done in my native language, that is, pt_br. http://blog.alura.com.br/aumentando-a-produtividade-com-butter-knife-no-android/

Answer (score 3):

```
textInputLatout.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            if (s.length() < 1) {
               textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(true);
                textInputLayout.setError("Please enter a value");
            }

            if (s.length() > 0) {
                textInputLayout.setError(null);
                textInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Why need `setError(null)`? `setErrorEnabled(false)` isn't enough?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly there is no built-in mechanism to achieve this behavior. I created `ViewUtils` class that helps me:

```
public final class ViewUtils {
    private ViewUtils() {}

    public static void resetTextInputErrorsOnTextChanged(TextInputLayout... textInputLayouts) {
        for (final TextInputLayout inputLayout : textInputLayouts) {
            EditText editText = inputLayout.getEditText();
            if(editText != null) {
                editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
                    @Override
                    public void beforeTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int count, final int after) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onTextChanged(final CharSequence s, final int start, final int before, final int count) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void afterTextChanged(final Editable s) {
                        if(inputLayout.getError() != null) inputLayout.setError(null);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And then you can easily use it in the client code:

```
ViewUtils.resetTextInputErrorsOnTextChanged(mEmailTextInputLayout, mPasswordTextInputLayout);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using KTX:

```
textInputLayout.editText?.doOnTextChanged { text, start, count, after ->
    if (text?.any(invalidCharacters.toCharArray()::contains) == true) {
      textInputLayout.error = "Invalid character entered: ${invalidCharacters}"
    } else {
      textInputLayout.error = null
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I've done it using a custom class that extends `TextInputLayout`. Uses a `TextWatcher` like the other answers, but there's no need to manually do anything after using this in the xml. It takes care of everything for you.

```
public class CustomTextInputLayout extends TextInputLayout {
public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomTextInputLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();
    initRemoveErrorWatcher();
}

private void initRemoveErrorWatcher() {
    EditText editText = getEditText();
    if (editText != null) {
        editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                setError(null);
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

To use, simply replace `TextInputLayout` in your xml with this:

```
<com.example.customViews.CustomTextInputLayout>...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the error display from TextInputLayout use:-

```
YourtextInputLayout.setErrorEnabled(false);
```

else
If you want to remove error display from edittextfield use:-

```
edittext_id.setError(null);
```

I suggest using **Textwatcher** fucntion in Android for more efficient validation handling..

eg:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() { 
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if (!validatefName()) {
                    return;
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

Removes error on touch

```
listOf(binding.userName, binding.password).forEach {
        it.setOnTouchListener { v, _ ->
            model.error.set(null)
            v.performClick()
            false
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

use textwatcher here's the link http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/02/android-textwatcher-example.html

Answer (score -1):

Use a if  else condition,if condition is true  set TextInoutLayoutObj.setError(null); if  its   false set your error there