# Hint text doesn´t appear in my Text Edit

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-6.0-marshmallow

I'm working on some views for my Android and trying to implement floating labels in text edit field, but even thought the label show when the element is focused, it doesn't show while it's not.

When it's not focused:

[image]

When it's focused:

[image]

And this is the code

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/input_layout_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input_plate"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Placas"
        android:textColorHint="@color/s_gray"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: I think you're talking about a known bug you need to update http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537413/textinputlayout-not-showing-edittext-hint-before-user-focus-on-it

Comment: you text color is same as hint color. change the style