# Separate hints for TextInputLayout and AutocompleteTextView

Tags: android, android-textinputlayout

I want to tell user about the pattern in which they should type location like below

[image]

So I have used AutocompleteTextView inside TextInputLayout like code below

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/profile_youraddress"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/profile_emailaddress"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_10"
        android:hint="@string/your_address"
    android:textColor="@color/home_primary_color">

    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/profile_addresstext"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Malviya Nagar, New Delhi, Delhi"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

The problem is that when the TextInputLayout is not in focus it two hints  overlap on each other like below 
[image]

How can I override TextInputLayout's hint on the AutocompleteTextView's hint in non focusable state? Any help will be appreciated.

**What I am looking For :**

When **not** in focus, the hint should be "Your Address" ("Malviya Nagar, New Delhi, Delhi" should be hidden) and when in focus hint should be "Malviya Nagar, New Delhi, Delhi".

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30537413/textinputlayout-not-showing-edittext-hint-before-user-focus-on-it

Comment: I have already checked that out... Thats not the issue here.... I am already using `compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'`.

Comment: What's the behavior you're looking for, exactly? That is, in your second image, do you want the hint to be "Your Address" or "Malviya Nagar, New Delhi, Delhi"?

Comment: Modified my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it using OnFocusChangeListener:

```
TextInputLayout text;
AutoCompleteTextView auto;
View.OnFocusChangeListener listener;

     text = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.profile_youraddress);
            auto = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.profile_addresstext);
            auto.setFocusable(true);

            listener = new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                    if (!hasFocus) {
                        auto.setHint("Malviya Nagar, New Delhi, Delhi");
                        text.setHint("");
                    }else {
                        auto.setHint("");
                        text.setHint("Your address");
                    }
                }
            };

            auto.setOnFocusChangeListener(listener);
```